# Fiori Master Detail App routing with mutliple parameters

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

I'm currently working on my first SAP Fiori App.
In SAP WebIDE I created a project from template using Master Detail and connected it to my oData Service.

If I run the unmodified App, everything works except that no data gets loaded on Detail View because the oData Service expects 2 parameters to get a unique record.

Now the problem is, if I modify the app to use 2 parameters and navigate to the Detail View, the Detail View loads, but doesn't even hit the oData Service. (No $batch Request in Chrome Dev Tools)

Modifications in manifest.json

```
    {
        "pattern": "JOBSSet/{Jobname}/{Jobcount}",
        "name": "object",
        "target": [
        "master",
        "object"
        ]
    }
```

Modification of Master Controller:

```
    _showDetail : function (oItem) {
            var bReplace = !Device.system.phone;
            // set the layout property of FCL control to show two columns
            this.getModel("appView").setProperty("/layout", "TwoColumnsMidExpanded");
            this.getRouter().navTo("object", {
                Jobname : encodeURIComponent(oItem.getBindingContext().getProperty("Jobname")),
                Jobcount : oItem.getBindingContext().getProperty("Jobcount")
            }, bReplace);
        }
```

Modification of Detail Controller:

```
_onObjectMatched : function (oEvent) {

            var sJobname =  decodeURIComponent(oEvent.getParameter("arguments").Jobname);
            var sJobcount =  oEvent.getParameter("arguments").Jobcount;

            this.getModel("appView").setProperty("/layout", "TwoColumnsMidExpanded");
            this.getModel().metadataLoaded().then( function() {
                var sObjectPath = this.getModel().createKey("JOBSSet", {
                    Jobname :  sJobname,
                    Jobcount : sJobcount
                });
                this._bindView("/" + sObjectPath);

            }.bind(this));
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior only happens when you run the app starting from its first page.

If you for example test the app in a smartphone (or using Chrome Dev Tools to simulate that) you'll see that when the app is opened directly to the detail page, there will be a network call to get the item detail. It will be a $batch call as well but inside it you will find a 'GET /JOBSSet(Jobname='x',Jobcount='y').

Basically what happens is the following: By default UI5 caches your data in `Context` objects (assuming you are using the `v2.ODataModel` class). When you run the app and see a list of "Jobs", the library already created a Context object for each record returned from your oData service.

If later on in the app you create a Context object (directly or indirectly, like the `bindElement` method) UI5 will check the given path - `/JOBSSet(Jobname='x',Jobcount='y')`. If there is already a Context linked with that path, then the Context should already exist in the main memory. So, no extra call should be needed.

Comment: But if I click on a Job, no Details are loaded. It shows the Detail View only with Data from the Jobsset, but doesn't fetch the details. Passing only one Parameter it tries to fetch the Details, but fails because of missing Parameter. So the question is, why does it fetch the Details when passing 1 Parameter, but doesn't even try to fetch them when passing 2 Parameters

Comment: No error in console/network section of the Chrome Dev Tools?

Comment: Also, I suggest you to try out the calls /JOBSSet(Jobname='x',Jobcount='y') and /JOBSSet(Jobname='x',Jobcount='y')/to_Details in your Gateway Client or browser to check if they work properly :-)

Comment: No Error in Dev Tool, it just doesn't hit the oData Service.
If I open a Tab with url to my oData and append /JOBSSet(Jobname='x',Jobcount='y') it loads the expected Job Details as XML

Comment: Please provide your detail view

Comment: Found the issue! I only had one entity and GetEntiySet and GetEntity. Moving the result of GetEntity to its own Entity fixed it. So it was a caching issue I guess